# Why is my RemoveItem function not working? - Context API - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-context

I am building a basket ecommerce app and my add to cart function is working fine, however when I use my remove item function it does not work, in fact it just adds the same item to the cart again but then the total displays as NaN.

I am just using .filter to return a new array without the items that I want removed by using its id, so not sure how this is happening.

If you want to replicate what I am talking about in code sandbox just click the add to cart button - then click top right basket icon to go to basket page - then click the minus button to remove the item.

code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/a2a82224701)

code below:

CartReducer.js

```
import {ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM} from '../Types'

export const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART: {
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
            }
        }
        case REMOVE_ITEM: {
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id),
            }
        }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

CartState.js

```
import { useReducer } from 'react'
import { CartContext } from './CartContext'
import {CartReducer} from './CartReducer'
import { SHOW_HIDE_CART, ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from '../Types'
import {products} from '../../pages/ProductDetailsPage'


export const CartState = ({children}) => {

    const initialState ={
        // showCart: false,
        products: products,
        cartItems: [],

    };

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, initialState);

    const addToCart = (item) => {
        dispatch({type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: item})
    };

 
    const removeItem = (id) => {
        dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ITEM, payload: id });
    };


    return (
        <CartContext.Provider 
            value={{
                products: state.products,
                cartItems: state.cartItems,  
                addToCart,
                removeItem,
            }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

BasketItem.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import image from '../assets/image.png'
// import { QuantityButtonDiv } from '../components/QuantityButtonDiv'
import plusButtonImage from '../assets/vector+.png'
import subtractButtonImage from '../assets/vector.png'
import { CartContext } from '../context/cart/CartContext'


export const BasketItem = ({item}) => {

    const { cartItems, removeItem } = useContext(CartContext);

    return (
        <div className="basket-item">
            <div className="title-div">
                <span>
                    {item.title}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="image-div">
                <img style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}} src={image}/>
            </div>
            <div className="price-div">
                <span>
                    £{item.price}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="basket-quantity-div">
                <button onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)} className="subtract-btn">
                    <img src={subtractButtonImage}/>
                </button>
                <span className="quantity-value">
                    {cartItems.length}
                </span>
                <button className="add-btn">
                    <img src={plusButtonImage}/>
                </button>
            </div>  
            <div className="total-div">
                £{cartItems.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0)}
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you double checked removeItem function?

In the dispatch you are sending { payload: id } and then the reducer get the value from payload.id. If you want to manage the reducer in this way you have to send in the payload an object { id: id } or shorthanded { id }

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, could you expand on what you mean? I just tried to implement the solution you mention it did not  solve the issue.